# Trying to create demo GIFs - How to get screen shots?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to create GIF animations for demoing my app.

In order to create animated GIFs of my app I need to get screen shots. 
I do know that I can just call the Form.paint(Graphics)-method. However this will not correctly give me a screen shot whilst in drag-and-drop.
What is the best way of getting screen shots in Codename One?

Answer (score 2):

I like doing this on the device so I use device video capture e.g. [this for iOS](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) & the [new adb command for Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html).

I sometimes use screen recording for desktop but not as often. You can then use one of the many mp4 to gif tools to convert the video to a GIF and also scale/remove frames/quality. I personally liked http://ezgif.com/

Comment: I would also add that you can use F2 if I remember correctly to do a screenshot in the simulator. Not sure if it will work during drag though.